# Last login time using the ASP.NET Membership API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-membership

I want to find out the last login time for a user in my ASP.NET MVC 1.0 application. I'm using the Membership provider for authentication. Although I'm able to retrieve the last login time using:

```
public ActionResult LogOn(string userName, string password, bool rememberMe, string returnUrl)
    {

        if (!ValidateLogOn(userName, password))
        {
            return View();
        }

        string lastLogin = Membership.GetUser(userName).LastLoginDate.ToString();
```

This returns the current time from the column LastLoginDate from aspnet_Membership table. Is there a way to tap into the former login time before the records get updated? 
Are cookies the only way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call the line before you do the `ValidateLogOn`. The LastLoginDate is updated if `Membership.ValidateUser` is called, and I suppose you call that in `ValidateLogOn`. So if you start your LogOn with your current last line then it should give you really the last login date....

Comment: I'm having a similar problem in ASP.NET WebForms. But I'm setting the authentication cookie which makes it rather more difficult- because I believe the user will stay logged in from the point they first create the user for the expiry of the cookie (50 years, apparently?).

What I need to do is somehow intercept the 'last activity' date before its updated when the user comes back to the page after their page has expired - or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The approach described here (Web Forms) when implemented similarly in MVC could be a more elegant solution - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16125/Getting-a-user-s-last-login-date-Before-it-s-updat